# How to do Starting inventory of a product with two costs?

Tags: odoo

In odoo  I know how to do an inventory of a product or product category ...., but I want to know how to do an inventory of a product with two different quantities with different costs. In case of real, avarage, and standard costing method.

**[UPDATE]**

after trying many ways with odoo i ends up with this idea but i don't know if its the best way.

**Average Costing:**
If i want to apply the average cost so i haven't any problem, just compute the average cost and set it in the Cost of the product, and put the hole quantity in one Inventory.

**Real Costing:** If i want to apply real costing so as we know the real costing method affected by the FIFO strategy, in this case set the cost of the first in quantity in the product cost then create an Inventory with the first quantity, same way with the second quantity, update the cost (as this will save the cost history) and create the second inventory with the second quantity.

This workaround gives me right inventory valuation.